# Error (1-10) in the MediaPlayer class

Tags: android

I want to create an radio by using on-line stream via http protocol. But I get error(1,-10). I don't know how to resolve it. Please for your help. Thanks! Below is my code:

```
String url = "http://";
        MediaPlayer radio = new MediaPlayer();
        radio.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
          try {
            radio.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            radio.prepareAsync();

        radio.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer radio) {
                    radio.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: 1) Not a valid URL 2) Do not use async unless you are willing to wait, I do not see any other code. Test with `prepare()` for now. 3) Where is your research?

Comment: 1)Url is not a problem, because I tryied with valid URL. 2) I used prepare() method and my program didn't work. 3)I don't know where problem is.

Comment: I always have the same errors: error(1,-10) and error(1,-1).

Comment: You still do not have any research here. There are tons of tutorials on how to use `MediaPlayer`. You should post as much detail in the question as possible.

Comment: Thanks! Jared Burrows for your help. I done it!